# Randomly placed sticky custom posts complemented by blog posts

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, loop, sticky-post

On my index.php file I am showing the most recent posts using the standard index.php file. However, I'd like to include a custom post type (named products) in this standard loop. Have about 6 products posts in total and would like to show them in a random order on the first 12 'slots' of the loop.

So a scenario could be:

```
1. Product
2. Post (most recent)
3. Post (most recent - 1)
4. Product
5. Post
...
12. Product/Post
13. Only posts from here on
... Post (oldest)
```

I have merged the products and posts in the loop as follow:

```
global $query_string;
parse_str( $query_string, $args );
$args['post_type'] = array( 'post', 'products' );
query_posts( $args );
if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); 
...
```

Hope this makes sense. Have no clue on how to approach it. Appreciate ideas!

Comment: You probably want something like this: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/96569/21376

Comment: thanks, definitely put me in the right direction. see below for my solution.

Answer (score 0):

This did it:

```
    $products = get_posts(array('post_type' => 'products'));
    $numbers = range(0, 8); 
    shuffle($numbers);

    $x = 0;
    foreach($products as $post) : setup_postdata($post);
        $product = new WP_Query(array('p'=>$post->ID,'post_type'=>'products'));
        if (!empty($product->posts)) array_splice($posts,$numbers[$x],0,$product->posts);
        $x++;
    endforeach;


    foreach($posts as $post) : setup_postdata($post);
    ...
```