# Insert/sticky multiple posts in multiple positions

Tags: loop, sticky-post

I'm attempting to do [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/121011/randomly-placed-sticky-custom-posts-complemented-by-blog-posts) but with multiple posts and specific positions. The post positions are hard coded right now, but will be pulled in from post meta. This code is only being ran on the homepage and the posts aren't paginated.

```
$essay_args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => get_option('posts_per_page'),
    'post__not_in' => array($post->ID),
    'post_type' => array('post')
);
$essays = get_posts( $essay_args );

$fixed_posts = get_posts(array('post_type'=>array('ad','book')));

$positions = array(2,5,10); // to be pulled in from ad/book posts
$x = 0;

foreach($fixed_posts as $fixed_post) : setup_postdata($post);
    $e_posts = new WP_Query(array('p'=>$fixed_post->ID,'post_type'=>array('ad','book')));
    if (!empty($e_posts->posts)) array_splice($essays,$positions[$x],0,$e_posts->posts);
    $x++;
 endforeach;

 foreach($essays as $essay) : setup_postdata($post);
    echo $essay->post_title . '<br>';
 endforeach;
```

Does it make more sense to do multiple WP_Query/get_posts requests for each post by id or does that tax the database too much? Is a there a cleaner way to do this?

Comment: You already have set of posts in `$fixed_posts`, why are you querying them one by one again with `WP_Query`?

Comment: I was using that to grab the correct id's. Are you suggesting I can use the id's already stored in `$fixed_posts` ?

Comment: Not sure I am quite following this but essentially it looks like "query me a post for this ID of a post I already have". Why? That whole foreach is tad weird overall.

Comment: That's what I was doing, but I can see that I can just splice the posts in with the id's I already have.

Answer (score 0):

You can try rebuilding an array of the two queries or splice the fixed_posts into the essays array. Maybe something like below.

```
$essay = get_posts();
$fixed_posts = get_posts();
$post_positions = array(2,5,10);
$x = 0;

foreach ($essays as $i => $essay) {
    if ($post_positions[$x] == $i) {
        $top_posts[] = $fixed_posts[$x];
        $x++;
    }

    $top_posts[] = $essay;
}

// Alternatively
foreach ($fixed_posts as $i => $fixed_post) {
    array_splice($essays, $post_positions[$i], 0, $fixed_post);
}
```

Comment: You seem to be missing a `continue;` in your `foreach`-loop inside the `if` statement. In the current setup you will be setting your values twice.