# How to Order Sticky Posts?

Tags: plugins, sticky-post

I've got a sticky post that i would like to move down to third position in between my regular posts on my site and for it to stay there permanently? I've already downloaded a few different sticky plugins and none of them can do this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is a similar question with an answer that might point you towards a solution -> http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/96347/insert-sticky-specific-post-into-loop-at-specific-location

Answer (score 0):

The order of sticky posts is based on the publish date (I think) - so simply adjust the publish dates to re-order them.

Comment: @cybmeta This *is* an answer: an attempt to solve the problem. Please read [answer].

Comment: Thanks @toscho - besides I don't have the reputation to comment and was only trying to help. The downvote makes me sad.

Comment: @Nathan Don’t let you discourage by a single down vote. We all get them eventually. :)