# Add generic page to WP_Query

Tags: query

I have a query that gets all my custom post types of Service. I need to add a generic page (Classes) to the query so that I can use the orderby argument. I know the ID of the page I need to add. How do I do this? Is there a way to add a specified page ID to the query?

Here is my existing code:

```
<?php $loop = new WP_Query( array( 
  'post_type' => 'service', 
  'posts_per_page' => -1, 
  'orderby' => 'menu_order',
  'order'   => 'ASC', ) ); 
?>
<?php while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>
  // Do stuff
<?php endwhile; wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: *Why* do you need to add it to the query versus using [`get_post()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post/) and displaying it at the beginning or end of your loop?

Comment: @Howdy_McGee can I still use the orderby arg on it that way? I need to order it like this: Service One (order 1), Service Two (order 2), Class (order 3), Service Four (order 4). I've also excluded some query code that relates to meta data in the services cpts.

Comment: When you [register your post type](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type) you can define what your post type [Supports](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type#supports). Menu Order (`menu_order`) specifically pertains to the support of `page-attributes`. If you register your post type with `page-attributes` then you'll be able to both set an order in the admin panel and query on that same order.

Comment: @Howdy_McGee I've checked and the Service CPT does support the page attributes and respects the orderby clause in my query. What I'm not sure of is how to add page Class into the *same* query so I can output the services and the page in the order their page attributes specify...if that makes sense

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish. It sounds like you're trying to split up page content in "Classes" and add your service in there. Maybe a [shortcode](https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API) would be easier. That query should order your Services by the attributes you set in each of the services posts.

Comment: I am honestly not sure what you are trying to accomplish either. Are you just trying to insert a post/page/CPT into the third spot in the Loop?

Comment: @s_ha_dum Yes essentially. I just want to be able to control the ordering of the services and this page. Essentially treating the page like another service. So I can list all the services but tell the Class page to appear in spot 3 (using the page attributes), for example.

Comment: Why not: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/96569/21376

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @s_ha_dum but the amount of Services will change (managed by a client) so I want it to be controlled by page attributes as it won't always need to be position 3. I think I will look for an alternative solution. This doesn't seem like a viable way to do it. Thank you both for your help.